# How to make series of test with protractor?

Tags: testing, protractor, automated-tests

What is canonical way to perform series of tests using protractor? Something like "visit every page on the list and check an aelemnt on it"? with a long list (hundreds/thousands of items) with all test results in one report?

Only way i am currently aware of is to supply varying part as a parameter and make humber of calls from the system (loop over the list of pages with awk, for example), which does not seem like a canonical way.

Comment: Could you please post sample Input_file and expected output please.

Comment: I feel there is no need for that, as i already have acceptable answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look into using `using()` test "multiplier" from [`jasmine-data-provider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider):

```
var urls = ["url1", ... "url2"];

using(urls, function (url) {
    it("should do something with url: '" + url + "'", function () {
        // test logic here
    });
});
```